# How to calculate origin of grid given periodic lat/long coords and X/Y offsets (ship navigation)

Tags: c++, latitude-longitude

Assume that I get periodic updates of own ship's position which contain both the current lat/long and the current X/Y offset (metres) from a unknown origin.

How do I calculate the lat/long of the grid origin? A solution in C++ would be doubly helpful.

Comment: This seems more like a maths question than a programming question.  `Given a set of N (lat,long) and N (x,y) points, determine (lat, long) for (0,0)`

Comment: I'm not sure if you are suggesting that Stackoverflow is not the correct place to ask this or that the tags are incorrect?

Comment: I don't think SO is the correct place for this.  You appear to be looking for an algorithm to solve your problem rather than trying to solve an issue with code that you have presented.